# Getting values from a sql table in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, pgadmin

I'm trying to get the ID from a table that is in a SQL Database, i'm using NetBeans to do this. Here's the code:

```
Statement busca = null;


String sql = ("select id from categoria where (nome = '" + valor_lista + "')");                      
//String sql = ("select id from categoria where nome ilike '%?%'");

                        busca.executeQuery(sql);

                        ResultSet rs = busca.getResultSet();



            while (rs.next()) {
                    int id = rs.getInt("id");   
            }        
               } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
```

My code doesn't shows the id, the variable valor_lista is from a jlist. In the end of the execution the console shows a `Null` message.

Comment: Paste your whole stack trace if you are getting null pointer exception or take time to explain your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`busca` is null. You should initialize it.

```
Statement busca = connection.createStatement();
```

assuming `conncetion` contains a `java.sql.Connection` instance.